# Web service software architecture

Tags: web-services, azure, architecture, software-design

I have a database which I consider to be my application and a website acting as a user interface for that application.  It is now time to add more user interfaces to my application (phone apps etc).

Keeping this in mind, I have come up with a web service architecture to feed data to all my user interfaces.  I would like to sanity check this with the brains on stack overflow.  Btw - this is all Azure hosted.

1. Database, as is.
2. Core web service - this handles all important methods and invokes the main processes on the DB.  For example, registration.  This will also automatically queue emails to be sent, etc.
3. Web Services for each UI (website, phone app) - these are specific methods for the UI data calls - e.g. GetDataForRegistrationPage - specific to the website and not needed for the app.  The app would have different requirements.

So far I think this is reasonable though I'm interested in your opinions.  I would like a bit of help with the next bit: how they communicate.

I would like the Core web service to be a WCF Service that can ONLY be accessed on named pipe endpoints - ensuring that only the client web services can communicate with them (I can guarantee they are on the same machine).
I would like the Client Web Services to bind to their applications by TCP or http.  The website will be on a separate machine but on the same network and so is a good contender for TCP.  The apps will of course be on clients and would be best as http I believe.

I am worried that I've introduced too many steps with this design.  Using registration as an example, the user would register using the website page which goes to the web server which would invoke the registration method on the website web service, which would invoke the registration method on the core web service, which would invoke registration on the database.

Thank you for your thoughts!

---

(I posted the below as answer but got told off.  If we really want to be anal about this then I guess no one should have posted anything as answer as there is no real answer - I was asking for opinions, but anyway...)

Just in case it is of any interest to others having similar design questions. I have decided to get rid of the core service idea and just use a class library shared between each client service.

Pros: Easier to develop, one less complication (setting up named pipes seems impossible to me) and one less process to get involved (even if it is on the same machine).

Cons: Each service now HAS to be on Azure, otherwise it cannot access the Azure storage facilities. I will be using the queue to schedule emails. With the first approach I could have potentially hosted one service on a completely separate platform.

Feel free to comment with any ideas or observations. Thank you for the input, Ramiramilu and Markus.

Comment: You question is purely opinion based. I would suggest you to do some metrices on your intended implementation, and in there is you have questions you can post it in here. To give you my 2 cents, there is no need for that named pipes services, you are only introduction one more level or latency in the over all request.

Comment: It is indeed opinion based - I'm asking for other people's experience which is valuable too.  The core service is another level in the middle, but it would be on the same machine as the client services.  Perhaps you're right and some actual metrics will be needed...

Comment: Yes metrices would help, because I can say go for WebAPI and another person can say go for NodeJS. How can we differentiate and how to evaluate which suits the best in your scenario. Also even if the core services sits on the same machine, what are you trying to achieve by separating it out?

Comment: The core services will do all the azure stuff.  Like adding jobs to the queue for the other bits of software that keep the whole system running.  It would be nice if this was done in one steady place as it is very important.

Separating out the different client services helps when I'm pushing updates to just one application - like a phone app.  It would be nice to not have to panic and test every single client when I am only updating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems to provide a good separation of concerns. Depending on the size of your project, it might be a bit too much. If you are looking for a way to simplify your architecture, here are my thoughts:

### Client WebServices

I'd propose to analyze how big the differences of the Client WebServices really are or whether it is possible to set up a common service for all clients. Even if you were able to move a lot of shared code to the Core WebService, you'd have to implementent very similar interfaces over and over again. Of course this implies that there won't be a specific WebService that is tailored to the needs of a specific client. If you build on WCF, you can also offer services with different bindings so that e.g. the WebSite accesses the service using a NetTcpBinding whereas another client communicates with the same service over a SOAP interface (WebHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding whichever fits your needs). This would be much more efficient because you'd not have to implement common building blocks like authentication and authorization for each Client WebService.

Also you might want to have a look at ASP.NET WebAPI and consider building a REST API that should be accessible from all devices - though it is as efficient as a TCP binding. You could also host your Web API in the WebSite project so that you can use it both from other client and for AJAX requests. As your WebSite is accessible from the internet anyway, this is also a good approach from an infrastructure point of view.

### Core WebService

You could substitute a class library for the Core WebService. The Client WebService(s) can integrate this much easier without having to deal with additional complexity, e.g. for authenticating at the Core WebService.
As you want to host the Core WebService on the same machine anyway, I'd only build a service if there is a strong reason for it. I can't come up with one now.

### Conclusion

If your requirements are only to add some clients with a limited set of capabilities, I'd suggest to add a Web API to your WebSite project and access it from the other clients. See this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for more information.

Comment: This is great stuff Markus and I will look more into this Web API stuff as you've suggested.

There will be a number of very similar methods on the different client services, however having dealt with mobile apps I can say that updating them is sometimes quite a pain.  You need to maintain the old version until they are all updated (which may be never) and I didn't want to risk disrupting the other clients when I updated just one.  If they were all in one service, then I risk disrupting the website and iphone app when I update the wp app.  Am I being too paranoid here?

Comment: Oh and the core service would not need any authentication on it if it only accepted named pipe connections.  So authentication wise it would be identical really.

Comment: @TimCharters: REST allows client and server to negotiate the format that they exchange data. If you need to introduce a new representation of a resource for a client, you can add a new content type and let the client request the new content type. The old clients continue to request the old format. Adds some effort, though.

Comment: @TimCharters: even if authentication is not too complicated for the Core Service, it adds a point that can break.